# jQuery AJAX referencing $(this) within success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a voting system which sends an id of the clicked item to a PHP script, the PHP updates the database and echos back the new vote counts via an JSON encoded array.

This is the jQuery:

```
$(".vote_up").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var vote = $(this).attr("class");
    var data = "id=" + id + "&vote=" + vote;
    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "vote.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                for(var x in data) {
                         $(".votes_up").find(id).html(data[x].vote_up);
                         $(".votes_down").find(id).html(data[x].vote_down);
                }
            }
    });
});
```

So when i construct the item in the first place, i take the record ID in the database and set it as the items ID. So what i'm trying to do is reference the exact item that was clicked and set it's HTML to the data thats coming back from the PHP. I've checked in Firebug and I'm getting correct data back but the count of votes isnt changing. Any ideas?

This is the PHP for reference:

```
$query = "SELECT vote_up, vote_down FROM posts WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
$output = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $output[] = Array(
        "vote_up" => $row['vote_up'],
        "vote_down" => $row['vote_down'],
    );
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: what does the html look like?

Comment: its all constructed by PHP but along the lines of <p class='votes_up' id='{FROM DB}'>The Item</p>

Comment: assuming you have same function for $(".votes_down").click ?

Comment: Are you saying you want `this` in the `success:` callback to be the element that was clicked?

Comment: yes, so whatever was clicked, i want to set the .html() to whatever is returned from the PHP

Comment: @benhowdle89: I just [added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982005/jquery-ajax-referencing-this-within-success-function/4982089#4982089). You can set the `context:` property of the AJAX request.

Comment: within the ajax success callback function, have you verified that it has access to the id variable? Try doing an `alert(id);` in there, it may be out of scope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want `this` in the `success:` callback to refer to the element that was clicked, just set the `context:` property for the AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
        context: this,  // set the context of the callbacks
        type: "POST",
        url: "vote.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
           // now "this" refers to the element that was clicked
        }
```

You can test it by doing something a little more generic, like:

```
$(this).html("yep, it works");
```

... then if that works, consider that it doesn't really make sense to do `.html()` on the same element in a loop, because each time `.html()` overwrites the entire content.

Use `.append()` instead if you're appending data from the loop:

```
for(var x in data) {
         $(this).append(data[x].vote_up);
         $(this).append(data[x].vote_down);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't:

```
$(".votes_up").find(id).html(...);
```

Really just need to be:

```
$('#' + id).html(..);
```

Comment: I see your point, its not working though. But by looking at it, i would have thought it would have worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable within the click() method callback, you'll be able to reference it within your ajax success callback. Something similar to this should do you:

```
$(".vote_up").click(function(){
// Assign the clicked element to a scoped variable...
var target = $(this);
var id = this.id;
var vote = $(this).attr("class");
var data = "id=" + id + "&vote=" + vote;
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vote.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            for(var x in data) {
                // Then refer to it within your callback
                target.html(data[x].vote_up);
                target.html(data[x].vote_down);
            }
        }
    });
});
```